# How to generate a mixed-case hash in Python?

Tags: python, hash, mixed-case

I am having a hard time figuring out a reasonable way to generate a mixed-case hash in Python.

I want to generate something like: aZeEe9E

Right now I'm using MD5, which doesn't generate case-sensitive hashes.

Do any of you know how to generate a hash value consisting of upper- and lower- case characters + numbers?

-

Okay, GregS's advice worked like a charm (on the first try!):

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> import hashlib, base64
>>> s = 'http://gooogle.com'
>>> hash = hashlib.md5(s).digest()
>>> print hash
46c4f333fae34078a68393213bb9272d
>>> print base64.b64encode(hash)
NDZjNGYzMzNmYWUzNDA3OGE2ODM5MzIxM2JiOTI3MmQ=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can base64 encode the output of the hash. This has a couple of additional characters beyond those you mentioned.

Comment: That is an interesting idea!  I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: Thanks GregS!  I had to do a reply to the question in order to be able to include code...but that is SO's fault.

THANK YOU!

Comment: @pyrony, edit your original question rather than adding "pseudo-answers" -- no fault of SO, just use it properly!-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [base64-encoded](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) hashes?